# Are there eSIM-based cellular plans suitable for travel (mainly Europe and USA)?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, roaming

An eSIM (embedded SIM card) allows setting a cellular service without getting a physical SIM card, so it appears very suitable for travel. Are there cellular providers that provide this option?

Currently the only provider I know of is the [Google Fi project](https://fi.google.com/about/) but it's suitable mainly for US residents (this is the requirement: I don't know if they enforce it), and its prices are significantly higher than the average price in Europe.

Comment: Project Fi issues normal SIM cards. I haven't heard of them supporting eSIM as they only support a restricted set of devices anyway.

Comment: they support esim - at least for the pixel devices

Comment: Google Fi prices are quite a bit more expensive than a local plan in any given country but still cheaper than many roaming prices. I am not sure I understand how eSIM are particularly suited for travel, it's more important to find a provider with attractive roaming costs.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, there is.**

You already answered the question yourself, there is a plan suitable for travel from Google Project Fi. I got mine when I was in the US, then left for more than one year then came back. When I was not using the plan I put it in pause, so I would not have to pay the $20 for the basic service while keeping the phone number. I heard that you could even downgrade to Google Voice so you can still have the text and voice for free, albeit only from your browser but it appeared to be a little complicated to set it up. The phone I have does not even have the eSIM to do all this.

If you want a local eSIM for your travel to have a local number, I only know [Singtel](https://www.singtel.com/personal/i/phones-plans/mobile/esim) from Singapore. However they don't make clear if they support devices other than the Samsung Gear S3 LTE. They also don't make clear if they will provide any plan with the eSIM, like a pre-paid.

In theory any operator supporting the Apple Watch Series 3 LTE should also support the eSIM ([there is a list here](https://www.apple.com/watch/cellular/)). However, it is also not clear if the operators will accept any eSIM device other than the ones they support.

PS: On a second thought, I've been searching about the advantages of eSIM and I found none for me. The few advantages that may be good for some people is that you can keep multiple eSIM in devices, like those dual SIM phones, except that the limit must be much higher. Other than that, the number of steps and time taken to setup, keep and terminate a cell phone plan seems to be almost the same. Other people may find easier to call the operator to get a eSIM swap (if they speak a language supported by the operator) instead of prying the SIM from the tray. Others may also find good the 10g or so weight reduction of the phone.

Comment: You lived in the US or merely visited when you got your Google Fi plan?

Comment: I lived for a few months. I think they require a US credit card and they deliver the SIM card only to a US address in order to sign to Project Fi. On my experience, getting a US credit card is quite easy if you are staying for at least two weeks in the US.